# I Don't want to show some tables and some column in mysql while generating my record

Tags: mysql

Since I have given to administrator to created the form dynamically.when he created form,What I have done is I have created the table for the form dynamically.Every thing is working fine.Now **I want to show  table and column for report generation**.In that I don't want to show **(userlogin,place,venue)** table for report generation and three columns **(user_id,user_common_id,ayear)** these three column are common for all the table which I created dynamically . I have given my code what I have done so far.

Guide me How to write the mysql query for this.

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "event");
    $result = $mysqli->query("SHOW TABLES");
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_row() )
    {
    $table = $row[0];
    echo '<h3>',$table,'</h3>';
    $result1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM $table where ayear='1'");
    if($result1) 
    {
    echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="db-table">';
    $column = $mysqli->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table");
    echo '<tr>';
    while($row3 = $column->fetch_row() ) 
    {
    echo '<th>'.$row3[0].'</th>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    while($row2 = $result1->fetch_row() ) 
    {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($row2 as $key=>$value) {
    echo '<td>',$value,'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table><br />';
    }
    }
    $mysqli->close();
    ?>
```

When admin created the forms, here is code for dynamic table and columns.for better projection

```
$query1="create table ".$porg."(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,".$VALUES.",user_id int(11),user_common_id int(11),ayear varchar(30),PRIMARY KEY (id)) ENGINE = INNODB"; 
      $result=mysql_query($query1);
```

Comment: Change `select *` to `select col1, col2, col3, ...`, just selecting the columns you want.

Comment: This application was already running three years, please see my query  SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table . year wise the report has to come.For all the table the column name is different apart from last three column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the tables and columns you want to skip in arrays, then use `in_array()` to test the name before showing it.

Use `fetch_assoc` rather than `fetch_row` so you get the column names in the array keys.

```
<?php
    $skip_tables = array('userlogin', 'place', 'venue');
    $skip_columns = array('user_id', 'user_common_id', 'ayear');
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "event");
    $result = $mysqli->query("SHOW TABLES");
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_row() )
    {
      $table = $row[0];
      if (in_array($table, $skip_tables)) {
        continue;
      }
      echo '<h3>',$table,'</h3>';
      $result1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM $table where ayear='1'");
      if($result1) 
      {
        echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="db-table">';
        $column = $mysqli->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table");
        echo '<tr>';
        while($row3 = $column->fetch_row() ) 
        {
          if (!in_array($row3[0], $skip_columns)) {
            echo '<th>'.$row3[0].'</th>';
          }
        }
        echo '</tr>';
        while($row2 = $result1->fetch_assoc() ) 
        {
          echo '<tr>';
          foreach($row2 as $key=>$value) {
            if (!in_array($key, $skip_columns)) {
              echo '<td>',$value,'</td>';
            }
          }
          echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table><br />';
      }
    }
    $mysqli->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: duplicate [alert](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32557907/1816093) from OP.  Close or Have deleted mine if you want