# How to find only specific tables and specific column names in my database using mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, schema

Since I have given to administrator to created the form dynamically.when he created form,What I have done is I have created the table for the form dynamically.Every thing is working fine.Now I want to show specific table and specific column for report generation.

**My questions are :**

1. I don't want to show (userlogin,place,venue) table for report generation and three columns (user_id,user_common_id,ayear) these three column are common for all the table which I created dynamically.
2. Based on  every year(2013,2014,2015) I want to generate the report.This i will send in form  to mysql while generation report.I want to list what are the forms  I have created dynamically.
3. How to write the query for that.

I have given my code also so far what I have done is here:

```
    <?php
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "event");
        $result = $mysqli->query("SHOW TABLES");
        while ( $row = $result->fetch_row() )
        {
            $table = $row[0];
            echo '<h3>',$table,'</h3>';
            $result1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM $table where ayear='2014'");
            if($result1) 
            {
                echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="db-table">';
                $column = $mysqli->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table");
                echo '<tr>';
                while($row3 = $column->fetch_row() ) 
                {
                    echo '<th>'.$row3[0].'</th>';
                }
                echo '</tr>';
                while($row2 = $result1->fetch_row() ) 
                {
                    echo '<tr>';
                    foreach($row2 as $key=>$value) {
                        echo '<td>',$value,'</td>';
                    }
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
                echo '</table><br />';
            }
        }
        $mysqli->close();
    ?>
```

### Here are the results

(to be filled in)

### Here are the expected results

```
id  Date        No_of_Days  Particulars         user_id     user_common_id  ayear
--  --------    ----------  ----------------    --------    --------------  -----
1   20/07/2013  1           Film Show on...     16          311             1
2   29/08/2013  1           Drama on ...        16          318             1
3   08/03/2014  1           Video Conferen..    10          621             1
```

Comment: you can read the schema information from the database and exclude certain tables and columns. As for #2, clueless

Comment: Drew thanks for you info. What I have read from google I done that. could you please help me to complete work for above code. because I am struggling

Comment: I cannot really understand #2, and will let someone else handle that one, unless you are talking about a datetime in a table, in which case, you probably know as much as me.

Comment: I make you clear. in this query I want to remove SELECT * FROM $table where ayear='1' (table names: userlogin,place,venue )I don't want to show these table.   2.SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table('user_id,user_common_id,ayear') I don't want to show these columns .

Comment: check the question ayear='1' nothing but ayear='2014' here i was given the primary key. that i will pass from the form while generationg  report

Comment: I will look in 6hours. It is 3am :) gotta close my eyes

Comment: THanks drew I believe you. good night I hope you got my concept.

Comment: ok, where are we at now? Can you please show table structure through posting results of `show create table myTableName` in an [edit] to question, some sample data (a few rows), and anything else that would help someone ... to help. Thanks

Comment: ok thanks I will ask new question.every thing is there drew.it is clear only

Comment: if you ask a new question without documenting the table, it is a dupe question and subject to people getting annoyed and closing it. So I will re-read it, but you need to improve your question style

Comment: see edited question at bottom

Comment: and at this point you already have a duplicate question going here. Here is the other [one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32556820/1816093). They get closed.

Comment: I want answer why stackoverflow offering the service, I have given my code  please understand what I have tried so far

Comment: I do sir, I am just waking up sorry. My brain is like at 20%. Please delete your duplicate question, we will work it here

Answer (score 1):

First I present this little chunk, could be useful for others later.

```
select table_name,column_name,ordinal_position from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'event'
order by table_name,ordinal_position
```

Now on to yours.

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "event");
    $result = $mysqli->query("SHOW TABLES");
    $dontDisplay = array('user_id','user_common_id','ayear');
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_row() )
    {   $table = $row[0];
        echo '<h3>',$table,'</h3>';
        $iterationOrdIgnore=array();
        $result1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM $table where ayear='2014'");
        if($result1) 
        {   $ff = $result1->fetch_fields();
            $iLoop=0;
            foreach ($ff as $oneF) {
                if (in_array($oneF->name, $dontDisplay)) {
                    $iterationOrdIgnore[]=$iLoop;
                }
                $iLoop++;
            }
            echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="db-table">';
            $column = $mysqli->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table where field not in ('user_id','user_common_id','ayear')");
            echo '<tr>';
            while($row3 = $column->fetch_row() ) 
            {   echo '<th>'.$row3[0].'</th>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';

            while($row2 = $result1->fetch_row() ) 
            {   echo '<tr>';
                $iLoop=0;
                foreach($row2 as $key=>$value) {
                    if (!in_array($iLoop, $iterationOrdIgnore)) {
                        echo "<td>".$value."</td>";
                    }
                    $iLoop++;
                }
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            echo '</table><br />';
        }
    }
    $mysqli->close();
```

I used the `$dontDisplay` array for the column names not to display.

Each table you work against can be expected to have columns in different ordinal positions (of course). So the array `$iterationOrdIgnore` held the ordinal positions for the table you are working on ... to ignore.

fetch_fields() is used against the resultset to get the column names to drive the above `$iterationOrdIgnore`.

When the column values are echoed, the ones to ignore, are ignored.

Also, keep a close eye on these two lines far apart from one another.

```
$dontDisplay = array('user_id','user_common_id','ayear');

and

$column = $mysqli->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table where field not in ('user_id','user_common_id','ayear')");
```

Combine them somehow for **less error-prone** cases where you modify one, and not the other. But this was a quick attempt to show it works. It can certainly be cleaned up.

See Manual page for [fetch_fields](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php) and [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

### Schema (for others to test)

```
create table t1
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    colQ int not null,
    colR int not null,
    particulars varchar(50) not null,
    user_id int not null,
    user_common_id int not null,
    ayear int not null
);
insert t1(colq,colr,particulars,user_id,user_common_id,ayear) values (1,1,'blah blah 1',1,1,2014),(2,2,'blah blah 2',2,2,2013),(3,3,'blah blah 3',3,3,2012);

create table t2
(   -- different table ordering of columns
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    particulars varchar(50) not null,
    ayear int not null,
    colQ int not null,
    user_id int not null,
    colR int not null,
    user_common_id int not null
);
insert t2(colq,colr,particulars,user_id,user_common_id,ayear) values (4,4,'Show 1',1,1,2014),(9,9,'Show 2',2,2,2013),(13,13,'Show 3',3,3,2012);
insert t2(colq,colr,particulars,user_id,user_common_id,ayear) values (99,99,'2014 2014 2014',1,1,2014),(9,9,'Show 2',2,2,2013),(13,13,'Show 3',3,3,2012);
```

Comment: see table is dynamically coming,column name also dynmaically coming.please check question  I have given my excepted result there last three column field and column should not come in output

Comment: Now I hope You understood my question. please help me  to complete this work. how to remove  last three column field and column values should not come in output

Comment: I am working it ... a few minutes

Comment: if you have any query please ask me because I only done the entire application

Comment: @Drew *"First I present this little chunk"* - Little huh? wow... I'd hate to see the "big" chunk.